# Ubuntu X terminal emulator

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

Whenever I press Ctrl+Alt+T, X terminal emulator opens up instead of Gnome terminal. I dont know why. What is this x terminal emulator and what does it do? How is it different from Gnome terminal?

Comment: This likely is not a fresh default installation? By default, it would be Gnome Terminal that opens. If no better solution pops up, a workaround would be to delete the existing keybinding to open a terminal and create your own shortcut for the command "gnome-terminal".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fully working workaround**

A very easy and fully working workaround would be to head to Settings - Keyboard Shortcuts". Disable the existing keybinding for "Launch Terminal" under "Launchers", and add a custom shortcut at the end of the list that executes `gnome-terminal` or perhaps `gnome-terminal.wrapper`.

**Debugging the issue**

What you observe points to some misconfiguring in your particular system. While the workaround will be fully satisfactory, you may be interested to investigate:

**1. Checking dconf setting for default terminal**

The factory-installed keybinding "Launch terminal" launches the default terminal. Check which executable is defined as your default terminal

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec
```

On a default Ubuntu installation, you will get `'x-terminal-emulator'`. If it is different for you, then change it to default with the command

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal
```

gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg

Verify if that key now points to `x-terminal-emulator`. If not, then set that key explicitly because then apparently that is not the default for your system:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'x-terminal-emulator'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg '-e'
```

If nothing was different on your system in this step, them move to 2.

**2. Check system default terminal emulator**

Trace back to what `x-terminal-emulator` refers. On a standard Ubuntu installation, the default keybinding in Ubuntu to open a terminal executes `x-terminal-emulator`. This is actually a link to `/etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator`. The latter in turn links to `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper`. For you, x-terminal-emulator may link to something else.

Trace it as following:

- Find out where `x-terminal-emulator` resides

  which x-terminal-emulator
- Identify the nature of the file:

  file $(which x-terminal-emulator)

Then, in a similar way, investigate the linked files. Somewhere in your install, the chain may be different. Most likely would be that `etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator` for you points to another terminal (i.e. x-term). If that is the case, the cleanest way to correct it would be to reconfigure your alternatives:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Type the selection number corresponding to `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper`. This will remove the existing `etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator` and replace it by a symlink to `gnome-terminal.wrapper`.

Comment: Thanks @vanadium......I did exactly what you asked (at the end of your answer) and it worked..thanks again :)

Comment: Maybe I should have started with the "update-alternatives" ;)